# Rewrite not redirect in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hello I would like to rewrite :

example.com/file

to

example.com

in  htaccess I don't want to redirect example.com/file to example but rewrite .What would I input in htaccess  thank you

Comment: _“What would I input in htaccess”_ – how about first of all you put some _research_ effort into this …?

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^file$ / [L]
</IfModule>
```